# Order list of multiple items in Python by value

Tags: python, list

I created a list with multiple items.

For example:

```
highScoreList = [["Dummy1",40,50],["Dummy2",100,80],["Dummy3",100,90]]
```

I'm trying to sort this based on values. First of all it should sort by the biggest 2nd value (here: 100 is bigger than 40).

If there are some elements which have the same 2nd element (here: 100 and 100), I still want to sort them using the 3rd element. The smaller the 3rd element, the higher it should rank (here: 80 is smaller than 90).

The result should be:

```
Dummy2 100 
Dummy3 100
Dummy1 40
```

I wrote some similar code in the past for a set using only 1 score value.

```
def printHighScoreList():
    descender = ((key,highScoreList[key]) for key in sorted(highScoreList,key=highScoreList.get, reverse=True))
    for key, value in descender:
       print(key, value)
```

Comment: That is not a set.  It is a list of lists.  Sets are denoted by curly braces: `{1, 2, 3}`.

Comment: @iCodez You're completely correct. I'm sorry I was confused. Updated my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the sorting using a compound key.  Since you want the list of lists to be sorted in reverse based on the first index, invert the key for the first index while using the second index as is:

```
highScoreList.sort(key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[2]))
```

`highScoreList` is now sorted correctly:

```
[['Dummy2', 100, 80], ['Dummy3', 100, 90], ['Dummy1', 40, 50]]
```

While the double sort method from @BHATIRSHAD's answer takes 3.39us (on your list on my machine for 10k loops), the method above takes just 1.5us.

Answer (score 2):

Sort the list in ascending order on third element and then sort the resultant list in decending order based on 2nd element of the list. Demo:

```
>>> highScoreList = [["Dummy1",40,50],["Dummy2",100,80],["Dummy3",100,90]]
>>> sorted(sorted(highScoreList, key=lambda x:x[2]),key=lambda x:x[1],reverse=True)
[['Dummy2', 100, 80], ['Dummy3', 100, 90], ['Dummy1', 40, 50]]
```